# Postgresql INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... WHERE not triggering

Tags: postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.6

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE import_files (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    file        TEXT NOT NULL,
    volume      TEXT NOT NULL,
    lastimport  DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
    UNIQUE (file,volume)
)
```

I am trying to import data into the table, such that if a combination of `file`
and `volume` does not already exist in the table, a new row should be added,
otherwise if there is an existing row, that row should be updated so that
`lastimport` is today's date.

However I do not want to do any update if that row is already todays date (the
same rows may be presented many times a day).

I am trying to use Postgresql 9.6's new `ON CONFLICT` clause for this, as follows:

```
INSERT INTO import_files(file,volume) 
VALUES('MyFile1', 'VolA')
ON CONFLICT (file,volume) DO
    UPDATE SET lastimport = CURRENT_DATE
WHERE EXCLUDED.lastimport < CURRENT_DATE
RETURNING id
```

but it does not seem to be working for me. Initial import works fine, but for the
update case it does not seem to update even where the WHERE clause is true:

```
t1=> select * from import_files;
 id |  file   | volume | lastimport
----+---------+--------+------------
  1 | MyFile1 | VolA   | 2017-05-07
(1 row)

t1=>     INSERT INTO import_files(file,volume)
    VALUES('MyFile1', 'VolA')
    ON CONFLICT (file,volume) DO
        UPDATE SET lastimport = CURRENT_DATE
    WHERE EXCLUDED.lastimport < CURRENT_DATE
    RETURNING id
;
 id
----
(0 rows)

INSERT 0 0
```

Since today is 2017-05-08 I would have expected that row to be updated.

Have I misunderstood the purpose or usage of the WHERE clause in this context?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is embarrassingly simple ...

The `EXCLUDED` table contains the rows originally proposed for insertion, not the current rows that are being updated. I was not specifying a value for `lastimport` so it would have been populated with the default value - in this case that was `CURRENT_DATE`, so the where clause would never be true.

Instead I should have been using this:

```
t1=> INSERT INTO import_files(file,volume)
    VALUES('MyFile1', 'VolA')
    ON CONFLICT (file,volume) DO
        UPDATE SET lastimport = CURRENT_DATE
    WHERE import_files.lastimport < CURRENT_DATE
    RETURNING id
;
 id
----
  1
(1 row)

INSERT 0 1
```

The where clause should have been referencing the current row values with `import_files.lastimport` instead of the proposed values with `EXCLUDED.lastimport`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different approach that works on previous versions of PostgreSQL:

```
do $$
begin 
  insert into import_files (file,volume) values('MyFile1', 'VolA');
exception when unique_violation then
  update import_files 
  set lastimport = current_date 
  where file = 'MyFile1' and volume = 'VolA' and lastimport < current_date
end $$;
```

Note that this approach works *only if there are no deletions of rows of the table*.